# why queries inside snow scripting SQL procedures have compile time when they should already be compiled while compiling the procedure itself?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Working on my project we are executing queries on SF using python script which causes a high compile time for complex queries contributing 15-30% in total execution time of script. I was assuming if converted to snow scripting sql procedure , the overhead of compile time will go away however i see that even in snow scripting which are written in SQL format only , queries are being compiled every time they execute. Even if i put one statement several time in the same procedure and run it , every time it has been compiled . Why queries written in snow scripting sql procedures should have the compile time when they should already be compiled while compiling the procedure itself ? Is this a known challenge to SF platform ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899259/snowflake-procedures

Answer (score 1):

So try all these answers together, in other DB's like SQL Server a compiled stored procedure is converted to optimal code as "compile time" and cached, for faster execution. In SQL Server when you use parameterized SQL, it is also compile and cached, thus if you are changing one value the "compile cost" is saved for each subsequent use of the same SQL block.

In snowflake nether of these things happen, things are evaluated every time the SQL is seen. It's like a C/C#/Java verse JavaScript/Python/Perl thing.

There is working being done in this stage, as Nick listed. You are billed for this time, but this is different to execution on a warehouse, and does not use credits on your warehouses.

So instead of compile think of it "pre-warehouse work" and "on-warehouse work"

The main point to note is if you write very poor SQL like use 10MB INSERT instead of COPY commands (we did this at first, it was a lift and shift) the compile time can be more than the execution time, and given it happens for every command to can stall you warehouse usage behind poor compilation.

Anyways, back to your procedure, the loop is logically the same as running the loop on you laptop in your favorite language, the LOOP is evaluated and every execute command is also evaluated/executed.

Comment: Thanks....so conclusion is that SF is yet to implement the soft parsing and hard parsing thing for better total execution time.

Comment: Yes, you could use those words. But for the data loads they are tackling, normally 10-150ms of “query building” time is meaningless compared the execution time of ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake stored procedures are written in Javascipt and SQL Scripting, neither are compiled, they are interpreted at run time.

So considering that SQL are often submitted to the database via an API call, one should strive to use set-based processing over row / cursor based processing for performance.

One single query that processes 1M rows will outperform a query that processes 1 row and is called 1M times.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the query history, the SQL statements you call from inside of the SP are executed as child jobs. They are not different from the stand-alone statements you execute from UI. They need to be compiled like any other SQL statement.

Therefore putting them into an SP doesn't reduce the compilation time. You will also spend extra time compiling the SP (which is not significant in most cases).

If it's possible, writing the query as a plain SQL statement is usually the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake compilation is not the same as what is normally meant when talking about code compilation. Snowflake compilation includes such things as

-Parsing

-Semantic Analysis

-Query Rewrite component

-Metadata-based pruning (unique in Snowflake)

-Cost based optimizer (CBO)